# StrawberryShake: Generating classes using a client that needs token authentication

Tags: c#, .net-core, graphql, console-application, strawberryshake

I am following the [StrawberryShake documentation](https://chillicream.com/docs/strawberryshake/v13/get-started/console) to create a console application to download data from a GraqhQL API. The difference in my case is that my server has a URL and one does not get access to it without an authentication token. But in the example in the doc, they are building a simple server and have easy access to it.

From the 4th step, [Add a GraphQL client to your project using the CLI tools](https://chillicream.com/docs/strawberryshake/v13/get-started/console#step-4-add-a-graphql-client-to-your-project-using-the-cli-tools), I cannot go further because I cannot generate C# classes based on the schema. I suppose I should download the schema file first and then build the classes, neither of which I can accomplish this way.

The error message I get is:

> error HTTP_ERROR: Response status code does not indicate success: 403
> (Forbidden).

Is there anyone who has done this?

Installed NuGet packages in the Visual Studio project:

- StrawberryShake (13.8.1)
- StrawberryShake.CodeGeneration.CSharp (12.22.2)
- StrawberryShake.Transport.Http (13.9.1)

Comment: `I cannot go further because I cannot generate C# classes based on the schema.` Does it generate any errors thats blocking you from doing so?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. The error I get is `error HTTP_ERROR: Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden).`

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to initially generate the authentication token manually, you should then be able to get this working with additional parameters in your `init`-command, see : https://chillicream.com/docs/strawberryshake/v13/tooling

So this should be possible by adding something like, for example

```
--headers X-Hasura-Admin-Secret={ADMIN_SECRET}
```

or

```
--scheme Bearer --token {AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN}
```

This is quite easy to miss if you're just following along the **Get Started**-pages, as there are no mentions of/references to the **Tooling/CLI**-page where this is explained.